# Why is guard stopping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, guard, minitest

I have a rails application that I just threw guard and minitest and my gaurd file is

```
guard 'minitest', :cli => '--drb --format doc --color' do
  # with Minitest::Unit
  watch(%r|^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb|)
  watch(%r|^lib/(.*)([^/]+)\.rb|)     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r|^test/test_helper\.rb|)    { "test" }

  # Rails
  watch(%r|^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb|) { |m| "test/functional/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r|^app/helpers/(.*)\.rb|)     { |m| "test/helpers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r|^app/models/(.*)\.rb|)      { |m| "test/unit/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }  
end
```

but when i run guard i get a command prompt

```
bundle exec guard
22:14:12 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
22:14:12 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/trace/Sites/application'
1.9.3 (main):0 > 2 + 2
=> 4
```

Why am i getting this prompt. Any ideas... here are some of the gems i am using

**UPDATE...**

when i run `all minitest` then the tests run...but why do i have to run that...any ideas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What your seeing is the Guard interactor, which makes use of [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/). Normally the prompt looks a bit different, so I assume you've a `~/.pryrc` file with some configuration. With Guard 1.5.3, released yesterday, Guard ignores `~/.pryrc` and only evaluates `~/.guardrc` for the Pry configuration, so the normal Pry configuration is separated from the Guard Pry interactor.

When you're seeing this prompt, it means that Guard is waiting and has nothing to do. You can now start working and Guard automatically starts testing your app with minitest according to your file modifications and watcher configuration, or you can manually trigger an action.

You can get a list of the available actions with `help guard`. Some commands are generated depending on your Guard plugins and groups within your `Guardfile`. Here's an example of one of my projects:

```
$ bundle exec guard 
09:58:14 - INFO - Guard uses GNTP to send notifications.
09:58:14 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/michi/Repositories/extranett'
09:58:15 - INFO - Guard::Jasmine starts Unicorn test server on port 8888 in development environment.
09:58:17 - INFO - Waiting for Jasmine test runner at http://dnndev.me:8888/jasmine
09:58:23 - INFO - Run all Jasmine suites
09:58:23 - INFO - Run Jasmine suite at http://dnndev.me:8888/jasmine
09:58:41 - INFO - Finished in 8.853 seconds
09:58:41 - INFO - 896 specs, 0 failures
09:58:41 - INFO - Done.
09:58:41 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
09:58:41 - INFO - LiveReload 1.6 is waiting for a browser to connect.
[1] guard(main)> help guard
Guard
  all                Run all plugins.
  backend            Run all backend
  change             Trigger a file change.
  coffeescript       Run all coffeescript
  frontend           Run all frontend
  jasmine            Run all jasmine
  livereload         Run all livereload
  notification       Toggles the notifications.
  pause              Toggles the file listener.
  reload             Reload all plugins.
  rspec              Run all rspec
  show               Show all Guard plugins.
[2] guard(main)> exit
09:59:39 - INFO - Guard::Jasmine stops server.
09:59:39 - INFO - Bye bye...
```

Comment: If you want the specific Pry instance used by guard to have its own prompt (independent of one specified in .pryrc) then pass the `:prompt` option when starting pry https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#wiki-Config_per_instance   (ignore the `prompt_name` option, that wont be available until the next release)

Comment: @Netxpirat - is there a way to stop this and just have guard fire when i have made changes like before

Comment: @Trace Yes, you can pass the `-i` option to guard and disable the interactor: `bundle exec guard -i`

Comment: @banister I'm using `Pry.config.prompt` to set it dynamically depending on the listener state: https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/lib/guard/interactor.rb#L114-121